# T(n) = T(n - sqrt(n)) + T(sqrt(n)) + 1

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, recurrence

How to solve this recurrence?
Is **Induction** the only way to get the answer? If so, how would you guess the base case?

My guess was **O(logn)** but I'm not sure how to solve it.

Comment: I'll try to give you a few hints. Forget about `1` for a second (it's easy to handle it later and it doesn't change anything). `sqrt` also doesn't matter: it could be n/2, 1, whatever. Also it'll help to imagine a recurrence tree: each node has cost 1 (base case), value of each node is a sum of values of its children. The answer is the value in the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recurrence relation is:

```
T(1) = c
T(n) = T(n - sqrt(n)) + T(sqrt(n)) + 1
```

We can write out a few terms:

```
n    T(n)
-    ----
1    c
2    c + c + 1 = 2c + 1
3    2c+1 + c + 1 = 3c + 2
4    2c+1 + 2c+1 + 1 = 4c + 3
5    3c+2 + 2c+1 + 1 = 5c + 4
6    4c+3 + 2c+1 + 1 = 6c + 5
…    …
9    6c+5 + 3c+2 + 1 = 9c + 8
…    …
k    kc + k - 1 = k(c + 1) - 1
```

After trying some terms it sure looks linear. We can guess that T(n) = k(c + 1) - 1 and try to prove it.

Base case: T(1) = c = 1(c + 1) - 1 = c + 1 - 1 = c. Verified

Induction hypothesis: Assume T(n) = n(c + 1) - 1 for all n up to and including k

Induction step: Show T(k+1) = (k+1)(c+1) - 1. From the recurrence we have T(k+1) = T(k+1 - sqrt(k+1)) + T(sqrt(k+1)) + 1. From the induction hypothesis, this is equal to (k+1 - sqrt(k+1))(c + 1) - 1 + sqrt(k+1)(c + 1) - 1 + 1. Simplifying, this is (k+1)(c+1)-1-1+1 = (k + 1)(c + 1) - 1, as required.

Therefore, T(n) = n(c + 1) - 1, and T(n) = O(n) as a result.

Comment: This is correct, thank you for the complete answer. This way, if it was `T(n) = T(n - sqrt(n)) + T(sqrt(n)) + n` the running time would become **O(n.log n)**, which is similar to quick sort.